# Is there a possibility to get the Index of a selecte Item in a Mudlist?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0, mudblazor

I have a list of objects i print in a mudlist and i want to get the object behind the currently selected MudListItem.

I tried this already:

```
<MudList Clickable="true" @bind-SelectedItem="selectedItem" @bind-SelectedValue="selectedValue">

 @foreach (Branch branch in branches)
{
  <MudListItem Text="@branch.BranchName"></MudListItem>
}

</MudList>
```

```
@code {
    private List<Staff?> staffs = new List<Staff>();

    private List<Branch> branches = new List<Branch>();

    MudListItem selectedItem { get; set; }

        Staff staff = new Staff
            {
                FirstName = FirstName,
                LastName = LastName,
                Adr = adress,
                Br = branches[GetIndexOf(selectedItem)]
            };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign an index with the `value` attribute on `MudListItem`.
[Mudblazor Documentation - Lists/Selection](https://mudblazor.com/components/list#selection)

```
<MudListItem Text="@branch.BranchName" value="IndexOfbranch"></MudListItem>
```

The value of `value` (IndexOfbranch) will then be assigned to `selectedValue`

So you can then use it as

```
    Staff staff = new Staff
        {
            FirstName = FirstName,
            LastName = LastName,
            Adr = adress,
            Br = branches[selectedValue]
        };
```

[Mudblazor snippet, assign index](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYwIkFkzfzOfBCLg)